# MySQL Insert query takes around 100-300ms

Tags: linux, mysql

I have installed MySQL version 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 on Ubuntu LTS.
The exact same setup is installed on a cheap VPS for 5$/year.

If I execute the following query on Server A.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES (9, '_dt_slideshow_mode', 'revolution')
```

it takes around 150 - 300ms.

If I execute the same Query on Server B (the cheap VPS) it takes around 1.3ms.

The MySQL DB is used for a Wordpress installation (a fresh one).
The whole InnoDB size is around 700 MB

I have tried nearly everything to speed up MySQL.

```
 perl mysqltuner.pl --host 127.0.0.1
```

Tells me to:

```
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Configure your accounts with IP or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
```

This is the only thing I get.
DNS-Resolution is not needed, cause the PHP file accessing MySQL runs on the same host. Therefore it accesses the server through the IP directly.

These are my seetings on Server A:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 1M
max_connections = 120
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
performance_schema
```

Without them, the query speed is exactly the same.

Storage/Memory:
Server A (slow one)
RAID5 with 3x 3TB SATA
16GB RAM
Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2224 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 cores
CPU Load usually 2-5%

Server B
RAID10 SSD cached.
0.5GB RAM
1vCPU

I know, SSD cached storage is faster. But I can't imagine that this is the only root cause for this huge query time. If this would be the case, nobody would be able to use MySQL reasonably without SSDs...

Please help me and give me some advice on how to dive into this problem more deeply.

Thank you.

Edit1:

```
iostat -x 1
```

shows the following on Server A

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.99    0.00    3.99   25.69    0.00   64.34

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
dm-1             0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00  155.00    672.00     0.00   0.00   18.97     4.34    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    2.94  97.60
md128            0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00  155.00    596.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     3.85    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
sda              1.00     16.00     3.00  75.00    0.00    16.00   65.00    592.00    83.00  56.08   15.95     9.11    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.91  91.20
sdb              1.00      8.00     1.00  50.00    0.00     8.00   37.00    336.00    47.00  55.95   13.46     9.08    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.43  49.60
sdc             20.00    220.00    35.00  63.64    0.20    11.00   30.00    288.00    42.00  58.33   11.17     9.60    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.30  45.20
```

%iowait varies between 25-50 and sometimes up to 70%

And this is the result of Server B (cheap VPS but fast)

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
vda              0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00
```

I also ran a fio test.
I guess, this is selfexplenatory...

Read IOPS ~430
Write IOPS ~140

Server B (the cheap VPS) has:
Read IOPS 20k
Write IOPS 9k

```
fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=fiotest --filename=testfio --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=512M --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75
fiotest: (g=0): rw=randrw, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=64
fio-3.16
Starting 1 process
fiotest: Laying out IO file (1 file / 512MiB)

fiotest: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=3864948: Wed Feb  2 09:02:32 2022
  read: IOPS=419, BW=1678KiB/s (1718kB/s)(384MiB/234399msec)
   bw (  KiB/s): min=  224, max= 3360, per=100.00%, avg=1685.15, stdev=351.83, samples=466
   iops        : min=   56, max=  840, avg=421.28, stdev=87.96, samples=466
  write: IOPS=139, BW=559KiB/s (573kB/s)(128MiB/234399msec); 0 zone resets
   bw (  KiB/s): min=   24, max= 1064, per=100.00%, avg=560.75, stdev=135.81, samples=466
   iops        : min=    6, max=  266, avg=140.16, stdev=33.95, samples=466
  cpu          : usr=0.65%, sys=2.43%, ctx=109245, majf=0, minf=9
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.1%, >=64=100.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.1%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=98308,32764,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=64

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=1678KiB/s (1718kB/s), 1678KiB/s-1678KiB/s (1718kB/s-1718kB/s), io=384MiB (403MB), run=234399-234399msec
  WRITE: bw=559KiB/s (573kB/s), 559KiB/s-559KiB/s (573kB/s-573kB/s), io=128MiB (134MB), run=234399-234399msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    dm-1: ios=98567/34364, merge=0/0, ticks=4447296/39160024, in_queue=43607320, util=100.00%, aggrios=98584/34364, aggrmerge=0/0, aggrticks=0/0, aggrin_queue=0, aggrutil=0.00%
    md128: ios=98584/34364, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%, aggrios=44194/22388, aggrmerge=348/734, aggrticks=2079553/2509410, aggrin_queue=4462748, aggrutil=93.04%
  sdc: ios=44413/22300, merge=238/833, ticks=2152332/2501290, in_queue=4527180, util=92.33%
  sdb: ios=44216/22403, merge=436/670, ticks=1968059/2317829, in_queue=4160104, util=92.59%
  sda: ios=43954/22461, merge=372/700, ticks=2118268/2709112, in_queue=4700960, util=93.04%
```

The RAID is in an active state:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md128 : active raid5 sdc3[2] sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      5840248832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 7/22 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      9756672 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

And all disks reply to a smartctl test with:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Comment: How far apart (physically) are the client and server for the slow case?  Is either on in a country that actively censors data?

Comment: Tiny RAM, poor tuning, slow disk -- none of these can explain 300ms for a single-row Insert.  Going to the other side of the globe could explain it.

Comment: In both servers a local php script executes the query… therefore its apache -> php -> localhost -> mysqld. I have also tried to spin up a mysql docker container. The result is the same. I connected to the ip dorectly. It looks like is has to do with the filesystem? what else could i try?

Comment: If i have alook at this one: https://serverfault.com/questions/557205/mysql-performance-bottleneck-i-o-or-cpu it looks definiteley as i would have an disk io problem… now ghe question is: should i dive deeper in the toe actual system? Should i try to cache the RAID5 with SSD or should i do a RAID10 soley made with new SSDs? Thy also mentioned that one can offload the whole db into ram? How can i achieve that?

Comment: I guess i found the bottleneck. The Filesystem (SW RAID5 with LVM and EXT4) is always busy for some reason. Am i right?

Comment: The IOPS are horrible... Have a look at the edits...

Comment: Shouldn't LVM be turned off except when a snapshot is being taken?  What does "65536KB chunk" mean?